# Sharing a Folium Interactive Map w/ Embedded Markers

Tags: python, web-mapping, features, geopandas

I have been experimenting with a few Python packages that have great potential for my dissertation research.  Since I use pandas for pretty much everything, [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/) was a natural choice for working with spatial data (within the range of capability of the package), and the interactive properties of [folium](https://folium.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) are sweet.

In any case, I want to be able to share the maps that I have made with other folks who are not using or even familiar with IPython Notebook.  My test case is plotting the location of traffic cameras in DC.  (The [shapefile](http://opendatadc.org/ro/dataset/traffic-cameras/resource/cf98adef-2ceb-411c-840b-141fae0fc8cf) is provided to the public by [DCGIS](http://octo.dc.gov/DC/OCTO/Maps+and+Apps/Geospatial+Services) via [opendatadc.org](http://opendatadc.org/ro/), a new and growing source for District info.)  The [Notebook Viewer](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/) seemed like an obvious choice, but as can be seen from my rendered [gist](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/choct155/7846849), the maps are 1) static, and 2) displayed only in their final form.  (Markers were not added until the last map, even though they appear in the first one.)

I then thought I could leverage Mike Bostock's awesome viewer for interactive graphics, [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/).  I am missing something, however, because while [my map](http://bl.ocks.org/choct155/7818425) is now interactive, the markers have disappeared.

Has anyone run into this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't gotten json files to load with nbviewer yet, but here's two things that work in similar situations:

If you only use `map.simple_marker()` and similar functions, it's possible to completely embed the map HTML into the notebook. I haven't gotten this to work with json yet, but it looks like the upcoming version of follium allows templates, so it possibly can be inlined in the future. I have an example of this here:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/bburky/7763555/folium-ipython.ipynb

Also, you're running a SimpleHTTPServer but you don't need to. You can use the magic IPython `files/` url to refer to files in the directory that IPython was launched from. So you can use an iframe with a source `files/index.html`. However, I haven't been able to get that to work in the Notebook Viewer. Theoretically you should be able to include multiple files in the gist and make it work.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  This is exactly what I was looking for when I asked this question.  The inline will certainly work, but if you get embed to work as well, I would be interested in a follow up comment.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Great. There's been some recent activity on follium's github, hopefully it will be possible soon. The embed method actually does work, just not in the notebook viewer.

Comment: It looks like the notebook viewer has been updated, so the embed method works too now. It even successfully loads json.